# reactjs route redirect changes url but does not render page, page is empty

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a redirect code inside an if else of a component, in which I needed to validate first the user before the app decides where to go next. In this scenario, the user has entered in he needs to be redirected to a component called "EventEnd" with msg of "The event has ended, come back again soon".

Pls note that the code  `<Redirect/>` changes the url in the browser, just that the page is empty/blank, and during debug it is not hitting inside my EventEnd component, so It's totally not going there. Also, if I enter the url manually in the browser like this works, it renders the page as I wanted.
http://localhost:3000/0c546bbcc435cd3cb2751e4e5e36956fd9248136/event-end

here are the codes I tried for redirecting - all didn't work.

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";


const RouteUserToEventPage: React.FC<{}> = (props: any)  => {
  .........
  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (eventId)
    {
      getUserStatus(); //this is where I set the eventStatus
    } 
  }, [location])
  
  if (eventStatus === status.Late) {
    return (
      
      <Redirect exact
          to={{ pathname: `/${eventId}/event-end`}}
      />
    )}
  else {
    return <>test page</>
  }

  
};

export default RouteUserToEventPage;
```

this is my route file called index.tsx

```
 export const PrivateRoutes: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {
    
        const appModel = props.appModel;
        const hasEventInfo:boolean = appModel.event.value && appModel.event.value.event_id? true: false;
    
        if (!hasEventInfo){
            return <Event.RouteUserToEventPage {...props} appModel={appModel}></Event.RouteUserToEventPage>
        }
    
      return (
        <Switch>
         
          <Redirect to="/:eventId/event-end" />
          <Route path="/:eventId/event-end" exact component={EventEnd} />
        .....
          <Route component={PageNotFound} path="/page-not-found" />
          <Redirect to="/page-not-found" />
        </Switch>
      );
    };
```

things I have tried which all didn't work:

I have also tried adding `export default withRouter(RouteUserToEventPage)`

I have also tried returning a button then I can click with redirect

I have added this to my route file:

```
  <Route
          path={[ '/:eventId/event-end']}>

  <Switch>
         
          <Redirect to="/:eventId/event-end" /> -- originally wasnt there but i added this at some point coz of trial and error
          <Route path="/:eventId/event-end" exact component={EventEnd} />
     </Switch>
<Route/>
```

I added `exact`, I removed `push` from the redirect code
I made a very simple btn that calls this (calls another component which loads if I put in `Link to={{...}}` just to test other component (coz I thought maybe it's my component that has problem), but that also didn't work on redirect

```
  const redirectTest = () => {
    let id = "0c546e346cd00dace9dcf18f8389adb537c12c85";
    <Redirect push to={{ pathname: `/some-settings/${id}`}}
     />
  }
```

pls. do not suggest history as it doesn't apply in this. Also, I cannot use a btn click and even if I did, the sample redirectTest  doesn't work.

What am I missing here? It's been my whole day so far.

**UPDATE:**

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import "./index.css";
    import App from "./App";
    import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import store from "./store/store";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import * as agent from "./utils/agent";
    import * as actionCreators from "./store/actionCreators";
    import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import { TableContainer, Paper, Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, TableBody, TableFooter, TablePagination } from "@material-ui/core";
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
          
            <Route path="/:organization" component={App} />
            <Route
              component={() => {
                const [organizations, setOrganizations] = useState<organization[]>(
                  []
                );
    
                const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
                const getAllOrganizations = () => {
                  ......
                };
                useEffect(getAllOrganizations, [dispatch]);
                return (
                  <>
                 
                   
                    <TableContainer component={Paper} className={"organizations-list"}>
                     .............
                    </TableContainer>
                  
                  </>
                );
              }}
            />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
    
    reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include a more cohesive code example? Specifically in relationship to any `Router` components that are rendering the routes, switches, links, redirects, etc...? I suspect you've more than 1 router wrapping your app & components.

Comment: updated above, pls see. tnx

Comment: Any `Router` component(s)? I'm assuming you are using `react-router-dom` since that is what the components used and prop APIs resemble, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I am not sure what u are referring to React component but it is in index.tsx where we put all "routes". Index.tsx is being called direct from App.tsx        <MUITheme>
        {!user.loggedIn && <PublicRoutes {...props} appModel={appModel} />}
        {user.loggedIn && <PrivateRoutes {...props} appModel={appModel} />} --- this is the index.tsx
      </MUITheme>

Comment: If using `react-router-dom` then *somewhere* you should be rendering a `Router` component. You'd be seeing an error if you weren't. A `Router` provides the routing context that the `Switch`, `Route`,`Redirect`, and `Link` components all use. If you nest a `Router` within a `Router` though that can mess with overall functionality. I'm just asking the components that render a `Router` component and how they relate to the components rendering the routing components used.

Comment: not sure if this is what u're asking about (I'm a reactjs newbie, so pls  bear with me)  ReactDOM.render added in the code sample, tnx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227750/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-user742102).

Comment: Was Drew able to find a solution?  He's definitely right about you either having multiple `Switch` declarations or just missing routes because I don't see the `PrivateRoutes` being implemented in your main file.

Comment: I did not find the solution as I was not able to send the whole project, the private routes is being called in the app.tsx as indicated above though.